# Javascript object constructor

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I know a little bit about Javascript, but am still finding my way. I saw a tutorial on Javascript working with Socket.IO. I was trying to follow along, but was a little confused by this Javascript constructor, with header Online code. I have not seen this format before. Is this equivalent to the code I wrote below it? Is it proper to create a constructor with the var self = {...} method?

```
//Online code
//-------------------------
var Player = function(id){
var self = {
    x:250,
    y:250,
    id:id
}
return self;
}

//Equivalent?
//------------------------
var Player = function(id){
    var self = this;
    this.x = 250;
    this.y = 250;
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: hey yes, that both are objects

Answer (score 2):

If you create a constructor, you can re use it, any one can create an instance.
If you create a new object, only that one you can use.

```
var Player = function(id){
    var self = this;
    this.x = 250;
    this.y = 250;
    this.id = id;
}
const player = new Player(id)
```

In this case, the properties are part of the object, so, each Player will have them

If you return an object, like:

```
var Player = function(id){
var self = {
    x:250,
    y:250,
    id:id
}
return self;
}
```

this value will be assined to who calls the method, but the instance will be an empty obect

Answer (score 1):

The primary difference between the two functions is the way they are linked (or not linked) to the `prototype` object of the function.

This method is links the returned object to `Player.prototype`:

```js
var Player = function(id) {
  // var self = this; <== this doesn't do anything
  this.x = 250;
  this.y = 250;
  this.id = id;
}

let p = new Player('some id')
// linked to player protoype :
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(p) === Player.prototype) // true

// which means you get inheritence:
Player.prototype.talk = function() {
  console.log(this.id, "talking")
}
p.talk() // sees the talk method on Player
```

If you create a one-off object in the function and return that instead, it is no longer linked to the function prototype. It's just a regular old object returned from a function:

```js
var Player = function(id){
  var self = {
      x:250,
      y:250,
      id:id
  }
  return self;
}

let p = Player("some id")
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(p) === Player.prototype) // false

Player.prototype.talk = function(){console.log("hello")}

// no inheritence
try {   
  p.talk()    // <= that's an error 
  } catch(err){
  console.log("Error:", err)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example both funcions will ruturn the same object. So yes, they are equivalent in terms of result.

The differences are:

1. First function can be called itself (`var p1 = Player ("id")`) or using `new` keyword `var p2 = new Player ("id")`. `p1` and `p2` will be objects with the same properties. But they **will not be equal** (`p1 !== p2`) as they are different objects.

Second function can be called only with `new` keyword `var p3 = new Player ("id")` Calling without `new` returns `undefined`

2. First function cannot use [prototype based inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). Second can.

The proper way of creating constructors is to use second form. It is considered [good practice](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp).